# How to parse all elements inside a webpage through jquery in chrome console

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, console.log

There are multiple elements with class="black-links" nad html for the elements is like this

```
<a class="black-links">Hello Seattle</a>
<a class="black-links">Cowboys things</a>
```

Also I am using jquery, and i wrote

```
$(".black-links").html();
```

Which obviously gave me the html for the first element only. How can I fetch all the html inside all of the links()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `.each()` to loop through `.black-links`

```
$(".black-links").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).html());  //in your case you can use .text()
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have to cover multiple elements with same class selector `black-links`
 ,you need to loop it.you can use `for` or `each` to do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".black-links").each(function(){
console.log($(this).html());
 });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="black-links">Hello Seattle</a>
<a class="black-links">Cowboys things</a>
```